# On-click jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need some sort on onclick function for my jquery mobile/php website. The following on-click wont work...

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
_END;
$int = 0;
foreach (array_slice($list,1) as $value) {
    echo <<<_END
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-$int" id="checkbox-$int" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-$int">$value</label>   
    _END;
    $int = $int+1;
}
echo <<<_END
        </fieldset>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 
            $(".checkbox-1").click(function(){
                alert('clicked!');
            });
        </script>
    </div>
_END;
```

Comment: what is the error? Are you sure that class exists?

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery is using a class selector, you need to update to it used an ID selector to match the output.

Replace

```
$(".checkbox-1").click
```

with

```
$("#checkbox-1").click
```

Comment: The ID selector is certainly the route you want to go here, I suspect you may have other issues going on. Can you paste the browser markup output?

Comment: After looking at this a little more, is this your exact PHP? There Heredoc nested in the `foreach` is problematic. There cannot be any characters or whitespace preceding your closing `_END;`. Please see the PHP documentations for [Heredoc strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: @greaterweb , it seems that whitespaces were added by me. Sorry for that.

Comment: I changed to buttons in the end. Thanks for your help.